# Cannot connect to internet Windows XP/IE8 combination

Tags: windows-xp

I have a laptop running on windows XP with IE 8.  I have not used it in years and was going to give it to a friend.  Everything seems to work but many websites are refusing connection due to the windows and IE combination.  How do I update either windows or IE or both to make the machine useable.

Right now, I cannot connect to Yahoo, Google or any common search sites to download software updates.

Help!

Comment: Is the time and date correct? If these is out by several weeks the browser will reject all SSL certificates. Do your friend a favour and install either a more modern version of Windows or some flavour of Linux.

Comment: I still run XP, and I have no problems with running the latest Firefox and Chrome browsers: most sites work with these. There are several IEtab add-ons, which allow IE-specific functions (eg ActiveX) to run in Firefox tabs. If you make one of these browsers the default, the system will be perfectly usable.

Comment: Try to upgrade to Win10 or check if Linux could be installed. Would be better than sticking to an old System with known security issues that don't get fixed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your friend is technically competent and aware of the security implications of running a system that has no further security updates, do not give them this laptop, it will very likely result in them being compromised one way or another.

XP is out of support, as is IE8.  Using a different browser is an option, but as the IE engine is still going to be used for things like email, or the IETab option suggested by a commenter, it will still expose a vulnerable browser to the internet.

Upgrading to Windows 10 would be an option if your laptop specs are sufficient, otherwise you could consider a linux OS.